# LEFT JOIN (Join query not working properly while connecting two tables)

Tags: php, mysql, json, join

Here i am doing cab allocation module,here i will explain my requirement,admin allocate the cab to the employees in shift wise.this details i stored in **cab_allocation** allocation table.

> cab_allocation (Table Name)

```
allocationId          cabId    shiftTiming    from_allocationDate  to_allocationdate
1                     CBX100     1             2017-08-10             2017-08-20  
2                     CBX100     2             2017-08-10             2017-08-20
3                     CBX101     3             2017-08-10             2017-08-20
```

Here **cabId** CBX100 having two allocation and CBX101 having one allocation per day. after this i want to track this trip is happening or not, for this tracking details i stored in **trip_details** table

> trip_details (table name)

```
tripId    cabNo    shiftId   tripDate   startTime   endTime    tripStatus

 1       CBX100      1       2017-08-16  09:30:00    11:30:00       1
 2       CBX100      2       2017-08-16  12.10.00                   0
```

Here cabId CBX100 has completed his shiftId 1, shiftId start time is 09:30:00 and end time 11:30:00  and **tripStatus 1** that means this trip is **completed**.

Next cabId CBX100 has started second shift, start time is 12.10.00 , but this trip is not completed so there is no end time and tripstatus

Next cabId CBX101 has not started his trip, so there is no entry is this table,

Now my expected result is which are the trip is incomplete i want to take details in cab allocation. here cab_allocation table **allocationId** i am using forien key of trip_details table **tripId**.

> I Tried like this

```
    $sql = "SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation as a INNER JOIN trip_details as b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId where b.tripStatus != '1' and b.tripDate != '".$date."' UNION SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation as a LEFT JOIN trip_details as b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId where b.tripId IS NULL";

  $mysql = mysql_query($sql);
  $count =mysql_num_rows($mysql);
  if($count > 0){
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql)) {

        $data[] = $row;

      }
  $arrayName = array('status' => 'success', 'count' => $count, 'data' =>$data);
  echo json_encode($arrayName);
 } else {
    $arrayName = array('status' => 'error', 'data' =>'Data not found' );
    echo json_encode($arrayName);
 }
```

> I am getting Results

```
{
"status": "success",
"count": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "allocationId": "2",
        "date": "2017-08-12",
        "shiftTiming": "2",
        "cabId": "CBX100"
    },
    {
        "allocationId": "3",
        "date": "2017-08-12",
        "shiftTiming": "3",
        "cabId": "CBX101"
    }
]
}
```

Upto now exactly working fine, after this i have to add one more condition that is date period checking
**cabId -->CBX100 is allocated only for 10 days time period is 2017-08-10 INTO 2017-08-20, this details in cab allocation table,think like suppose today date 2017-08-09 means should not display the cab allocation details and suppose today date is 2017-08-21 that time also should not display cab allocation details, for this time we have to show {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}**

> This condition where i have to check (like how to add this condition in my query)

Comment: @Nawin, please check my expected results , i am not getting my expected results while adding the date condition, if know means post your answer

Comment: Why u are making a join to allocate_id and trip_id?

Comment: @Moiz Arif, in allocation table i stored the allocation details like , this cab(CBX100) is allocated to this shift(1) upto this date (2017-08-2017).so every day he has to complete his trip, so this trip completion details i am string in trip_details table.that what i am join two table here allocation id is the foreign key of tripId in trip_details

Comment: Make a left join on cabId and canNo it will work

Comment: @Moiz Arif Can please update your answer

Comment: Why we are giving the condition of tripId is null ?

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting ,it is not working properly like suppose there is trip started means in trip_details there is no entry that time we have to display allocation table how entry are there, but i am getting here {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}

Comment: Using brackets in your query might do the trick:  WHERE 
  b.tripDate='2017-08-16' AND (b.tripId is null OR b.tripStatus !='1')

Comment: @RWC I tried but i am getting {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}

Comment: @Swamym just need put the table structure, what you have to tried and what is expected result.

Comment: @Mr  Irfan, please see now my question i updated , i explained what i need

Comment: Please reserve the use of blockquote formatting (`>`) for quotations. Do not use it to "highlight" sections. You don't need formatting there at all; this should be set in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Check It out and update ..

```
$date = "2017-08-16";
$sql = "SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation as a INNER JOIN trip_details as b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId where b.tripStatus != 1 and b.tripDate != '".$date."' UNION SELECT a.allocationId, a.date, a.shiftTiming, a.cabId FROM cab_allocation as a LEFT JOIN trip_details as b ON a.allocationId = b.tripId where b.tripId IS NULL";
```

Comment: I tried your code i am getting {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}, note one thing in my trip_details table now there is no data, think like upto now there is no trip is started , actual results should come like  howmany alocation are there in allocation table that should come

Comment: b.tripStatus != '1', i am giving inside single quotation means it is working fine , from here where i have to give the date condition, this is my question also.

Comment: please check my comment and update date condition your code

Comment: Date condition like this i need ,  b.tripDate not equal, to today means i want display all allocation from allocation table bassed on cabId

Comment: @Mr Moiz Arif , this date condition already i wriiten, for me please see my allocation table (top of the page) from there i am given from_allocationDate and to_allocationdate, in this period only this functionality functionality should work, suppose today date not in this period means results should  {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}

Comment: If you are saying all trip only not for today than this query work

Comment: cabId -->CBX100 is allocated only for 10 days time period is 2017-08-10 INTO 2017-08-20, this details in cab allocation table,think like suppose today date 2017-08-09 means should not display the cab allocation details and suppose today date is 2017-08-21 that time also should not display cab allocation details, for this time we have to show {"status":"error","data":"Data not found"}

Comment: @ Mr,Moiz Arif, Are you there you are getting my question